# Is it correct to use "catered" in a sentence like "which is an technology originally catered for..."?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I wrote the following sentence which my tutor doubted it, but I cannot see the why. Can anyone help me figure it out?

More specific,  should `catered` be replaced as `caters` or `catering` or other forms? or there is no problem for the following sentence.

> Multi-sensor fusion is also known as  multi-sensor data fusion, which
>   is an emerging technology originally **catered** for the military needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you should ask your tutor to explain why...

Anyway, it should be *catering*. If you go to the time of "originally", *cater* indicates a continuing action, so you would use -ing verb form. As defined below, it is not a single action or event.

The definition here would be [***cater***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/cater) sense 2:

> *intransitive verb*
>   2) to take special pains in seeking to gratify another's needs or desires (with to or, in Brit. usage, for)

This is different from the other definitions (relating to catered meals and such), which could be considered as single events.

As for the preposition, I (American) would use *catering to*, but it seems BrE speakers use *catering for*.